# Populating drop down using petapoco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, petapoco

I have situation like this: Employee and Department are two tables and when I add new employee it should  retrieve all department Id from department table and list them in drop down for selection.
Please consider petapoco as I am using it to work with database coding.
Can anyone help me with the code that I should add in the model, view and controller (ASP.NET) for the same?